# Using data from MySQL database to populate a dropdown with Flask and jQuery

Tags: jquery, mysql, dynamic, flask, dropdown

I am making a very small website where database information is to be displayed depending on dropdown selection.
Lets say my database contains 2 tables, first one with companys with a ID and a name. The other one with Employees "linked" to these companies. E.G:

```
╔═════════════╦════════════╗
║ company_ID  ║ company    ║
╠═════════════╬════════════╣
║ 1           ║ Google     ║ 
║ 2           ║ H&M        ║ 
║ 3           ║ IKEA       ║ 
╚═════════════╩════════════╝

╔═════════════╦═════════════════╗
║ company_ID  ║ employee        ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ 1           ║ Google_emp1     ║ 
║ 1           ║ Google_emp2     ║ 
║ 2           ║ H&M_emp1        ║ 
║ 1           ║ Google_emp3     ║ 
║ 3           ║ IKEA_emp1       ║ 
║ 3           ║ IKEA_emp2       ║ 
║ 2           ║ H&M_emp2        ║ 
╚═════════════╩═════════════════╝
```

When one chooses 'Google' in the dropdown all the employees with company_ID of 1 is supposed to show up in the second dropdown (since Google's ID is 1 in this case).
**Problem:**
I need to pass my Flask variables to the .js-file to populate the dropdown.
At the moment the important part of the python-file looks like this:

```
def database():
    c, conn = connectionDB()

    compDB = c.execute("SELECT * FROM Companies")
    compDB = c.fetchall()

    empDB = c.execute("SELECT * FROM Employees")
    empDB = c.fetchall()

    return render_template("database.html", 
                            compDB = compDB,
                            empDB = empDB,
                            HEADERTEXT_LIST = HEADERTEXT_LIST)
```

The important part of my .html-file looks like this:

```
<select class="chzn-select" id="company" data-placeholder="Choose company" name="company">
    <option value=""></option>    
<!--Here is the appending supposed to start-->
</select>

<select class="chzn-select" id="employee" data-placeholder="Choose employee" name="employee">
    <option value=""></option>    
<!--Here is the appending (depending on company) supposed to start-->
</select>
```

(I actually have several layers, but it is the same principle)
My .js-file looks like this (I use chosen as styling):

```
$(function () {
            $('.chzn-select').chosen({
                no_results_text: "No results for: ",
                search_contains: true,
                single_backstroke_delete: false,
                disable_search: false,
                width: "200px",
            });
            $('#company').append($('<option value=""></option>'));
            $('#company').trigger("chosen:updated");

        });
```

Where my database information should be entered like this:

```
<option value="company_id">company</option>
```

**Question 1:**
How do I pass these variables from the .py-file so they can be manipulated by the .js-file? 
I mean, I could use Flask-logic but that is only interpreted in my .html-file.
**Question 2:**
What is the smartest way to populate these? some sort of for-loop? I am completely new to javascript, sorry for maybe asking the obvious.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Jinja2 templating in Flask you can create a JSON object in Python, for instance you can use python logic to create an object that looks like this from your query results:

```
object = [
    {"id": 1, "company": "Google", "employees": [
       {"name": "Mike"},
       {"name": "Jessica"},
    ]},
    {"id": 2, "company": "H&M", "employees": [...]},
    {"id": 3, "company": "Ikea", "employees": [...]},
]
```

Add this object to your render_template call:

```
return render_template("database.html", 
                        compDB = compDB,
                        empDB = empDB,
                        javascript = object,
                        HEADERTEXT_LIST = HEADERTEXT_LIST)
```

Then, within your template HTML you need to use 2 builtin Jinja2 filters to render the variable as JSON (this is a default part of Flask). Then here is the jQuery code I use to dynamically update the selects.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var myVariable = {{ javascript|tojson|safe }};

    var selectCompany = $('#company');
    var selectEmployee = $('#employee');

    selectCompany.empty();
    $.each(myVariable, function (index, value) {
        selectCompany.append(
            $('<option>', {
                value: index,
                text: value.name
            }, '</option>'))
    });

    updateEmployeeSelect();

    selectCompany.on('change', function() {
        updateEmployeeSelect();
    });

    function updateEmployeeSelect() {
        var selected = selectCompany.val();

        selectEmployee.empty();
        $.each(myVariable[selected].employees, 
            function (index, value) {
                selectEmployee.append(
                    $('<option>', { 
                        value: index, text: value.name
                    }, '</option>'))
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Also -- update, just realized I used jQuery above without explicitly stating it. You could replace the jQuery $.each() call with a basic for javascript for loop, e.g. a pattern like this:

```
for (var a = 0; a < myVariable.length; a++) {
    selectCompany.append(
        $('<option>', {
            value: a,
            text: myVariable[a].name
        }, '</option>'))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) i have a lot of layers in my database, still working on formatting the query results though..